# Loop through javascript array to build an HTML table with jade

Tags: javascript, loops, express, pug, html-table

I'm trying to render an HTML table (with jade) like in this picture :

[image]

The data is formatted as follow :

```
var menus = [
    {
        day: "Lundi",
        items: [
            { name: "item 1", price: 6.50 },
            { name: "item 2", price: 7 },
            { name: "item 3", price: 6.50 }
        ]
    },
    {
        day: "Mardi",
        items: [
            { name: "item 1", price: 6.5 },
            { name: "item 2", price: 7 }
        ]
    },
    {
        day: "Mercredi",
        items: [
            { name: "item 1", price: 6.5 },
            { name: "item 2", price: 7 },
            { name: "item 3", price: 6.5 }
        ]
    },
    {
        day: "Jeudi",
        items: [
            { name: "item 1", price: 6.5 },
            { name: "item 2", price: 7 },
            { name: "item 3", price: 6.5 }
        ]
    },
    {
        day: "Vendredi",
        items: [
            { name: "item 1", price: 6.5 },
            { name: "item 2", price: 7 }
        ]
    }
];
```

Here is what I have for now :

```
    table
    thead
        tr
            each menu in menus
                th= menu.day
    tbody
        // what kind of magic loop should I use here to go through menus' items ?
```

So, as you can see, I'm struggling to loop through each menu's items.
Do I need to format the `menus` array in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like the code below or you could format the json in your route before you pass it to the template to make it easier to loop through... doing it with the code below you are going to run into problems when you hit a td where an item is undefined, so you'd need an error check to ensure that there is a menu item.

```
    thead
            tr
                each menu in menus
                    th= menu.day
            tbody
                tr
                    each menu in menus
                        td= menu.items[0].name 
                tr
                    each menu in menus
                        td= menu.items[1].name 
                tr
                    each menu in menus
                        if (menu.items[2])
                            td= menu.items[2].name
                        else 
                            td= ""
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I can't control how many rows are needed. I wonder if re-formatting menus in the route is a good idea. Because I could need to use the data in another place, but in a different way.

Comment: @inwpitrust dont globally reform the data in your route just reform it to send to this particular template. or you could stick it in another loop dependent on the length of menus

Comment: To pass the reformatted data to the template, I need to do it in the route no? I'm not yet familiar with templates in express/jade.